# Importing CSV in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, csv, import

I am trying to import a .csv file in Symfony 2. I've created a file form and now I want to persist it in my database.

Here is my handler file where I want to make the .csv treatment and persist it:

```
public function process()
{
    if ($this->request->getMethod() == 'POST')
    {
        $this->form->bindRequest($this->request);

        $tableau = array();
        $i = 0;
        $c = 0;
        $num = 0;

        if (isset($_FILES['file']))
        {
            $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; 
            $handle = fopen($file,'r'); 
            $row = 1; 
            $handle = fopen("$file", "r"); 

            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
            {
                $num =+ count($data);
                $row++; 

                for ($c = $i; $c < $num; $c++)
                {
                    $tableau[$c] = $data[$c];
                    $i++;
                }
            }
        }
        $tableau[$c+1] = $i;

        /*
        if ($this->form->isValid())
        {
            print_r($this->form->getData());

            $this->onSuccess($this->form->getData());

            return true;
        }
        */
    }

    return false;
}
```

When I'm trying to test it some text appears on top of my page:

> Array ( [fichier] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile Object ( [test:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => [originalName:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => testcsv.csv [mimeType:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => text/csv [size:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 491 [error:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 0 [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpSr5O5S [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => phpSr5O5S ) )

I don't understand those things.

Comment: This looks like the output of the print_r function. Are you sure it is commented out as shown in the code above?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to do a proper symfony2 way you should create a symfony form to submit the file. For example:

```
// Your Controller.php
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('submitFile', 'file', array('label' => 'File to Submit'))
        ->getForm();

// Check if we are posting stuff
if ($request->getMethod('post') == 'POST') {
    // Bind request to the form
    $form->bindRequest($request);

    // If form is valid
    if ($form->isValid()) {
         // Get file
         $file = $form->get('submitFile');

         // Your csv file here when you hit submit button
         $file->getData();
    }

 }

return $this->render('YourBundle:YourControllerName:index.html.twig',
    array('form' => $form->createView(),)
);
```

Twig:

```
<!-- index.html.twig Twig part -->
{% extends "YourBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

{% block content %}
    <form action="" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
        {{ form_widget(form) }}

        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Dont forget that `{{ form_enctype(form) }}` is important to tell that we are sending file. Symfony2 will generate `enctype="multipart/form-data"` tag

Comment: Please update your answer as `bindRequest` has been deprecated. You should use now `bind` instead.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/25054420/1251563

Comment: You should use `$form->handleRequest($request)` since SF 2.3 and it will be the only way to do it when SF3.0 is out.

Comment: in SF3 it should be `->add('submitFile', FileType::class, array('label' => 'File to Submit'))` preceded by the use statement `use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;`

Answer (score 16):

If you do not want a form, you can do this:

```
public function processAction() {
    foreach($this->getRequest()->files as $file) { 
        if (($handle = fopen($file->getRealPath(), "r")) !== FALSE) {
            while(($row = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {
                var_dump($row); // process the row.
            }
        }
    }
    //return response.
}
```