# Trying to make a contact form example with symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony

Here I'm trying to fill in a contact form then send it. However when I fill in the form and click on send I have this exception :

```
UndefinedMethodException: Attempted to call method "bindRequest" on class "Symfony\Component\Form\Form" in /symfony/src/tuto/WelcomeBundle/Form/Handler/ContactHandler.php line 47.
```

This is the content of ContactHandler.php:

namespace tuto\WelcomeBundle\Form\Handler;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Form;
   use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

```
/**
* The ContactHandler.
* Use for manage your form submitions
*
* @author Abderrahim
*/
class ContactHandler
{
 protected $request;
 protected $form;
 protected $mailer;

 /**
 * Initialize the handler with the form and the request
 *
 * @param Form $form
 * @param Request $request
 * @param $mailer
 * 
 */
 public function __construct(Form $form, Request $request, $mailer)
 {
    $this->form = $form;
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->mailer = $mailer;
 }

 /**
 * Process form
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
  public function process()
 {
  // Check the method
  if ('POST' == $this->request->getMethod())
  {
      // Bind value with form
      $this->form->bindRequest($this->request);

      $data = $this->form->getData();
      $this->onSuccess($data);

      return true;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Send mail on success
 * 
 * @param array $data
 * 
 */
protected function onSuccess($data)
{
    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                ->setContentType('text/html')
                ->setSubject($data['subject'])
                ->setFrom($data['email'])
                ->setTo('xxxx@gmail.com')
                ->setBody($data['content']);

    $this->mailer->send($message);
}
}
```

Could you please give me any help !!

Comment: Have you tried `bind` instead?

Comment: Great, I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should replace

```
$this->form->bindRequest($this->request);
```

With

```
$this->form->bind($this->request);
```

As `bindRequest()` has deprecated.

Answer (score 5):

Use `$form->handleRequest($request);` to handle form submissions - http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#handling-form-submissions

Answer (score 2):

`bindRequest` was deprecated and removed, use `submit` method instead

Answer (score -3):

You should replace

```
$this->form->bindRequest($this->request);
```

with

```
$this->form->bind($this->request);
```

as `bindRequest()` has been deprecated.

Comment: copied answer from above line